# Using the minipage enviroment inside \newcommand

Tags: macros, floats, minipage, calculations

i want to put the `minipage` enviroment inside a `newcommand` to avoid typing.

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}

\newcommand{\MYfigure}[4]{
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=#1\textwidth]{images/#2}
        \caption{#4 #3}
    \end{figure}
}

\newcommand{\MYminipage}[3]{
    \begin{minipage}{(#1-0.3)*\textwidth}
        #2
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}{(1-#1-0.3)*\textwidth}
        #3
    \end{minipage}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \MYminipage{0.5}{\MYfigure{1}{imagename.jpg}{text}{text}}{\MYfigure{1}{imagename.jpg}{text}{text}}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

For `imagename.jpg` any image in a folder called `images` can be used. 
I think the problem are the calculations for the widths of the minipages (e.g. `(1-#1-0.3)*\textwidth`). That's why i already tried to use `\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}`.

EDIT:
To clarify what need: i want this but with the macro `\MYminipage`.

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{lmodern}

    \usepackage[nomessages]{fp}

        \newcommand{\MYfigure}[4]{
            \begin{figure}
                \centering
                \includegraphics[width=#1\textwidth]{images/#2}
                \caption{#4 #3}
            \end{figure}
        }

        %\newcommand{\MYminipage}[3]{
        %    \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr#1\textwidth-.3\textwidth\relax}
    %        #2
    %    \end{minipage}
    %    \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\textwidth-#1\textwidth-.3\textwidth\relax}
    %        #3
    %    \end{minipage}
    %}

    \begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{minipage}{.47 \textwidth}
        \MYfigure{1}{imagename.jpg}{text}{text}
        \end{minipage}
        \begin{minipage}{.47 \textwidth}
        \MYfigure{1}{imagename.jpg}{text}{text}
        \end{minipage}
    \end{frame}
    \end{document
```

The code Ulrich Diez suggests is:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}

\newcommand{\MYfigure}[4]{%%%
    \begin{figure}%%%
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=#1\textwidth]{images/#2}%%%
        \caption{#4 #3}%%%
    \end{figure}%%%
}%%%

\newcommand{\MYminipage}[3]{%%%
    \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr#1\textwidth-.3\textwidth\relax}%%
        #2%%%
    \end{minipage}%%%
    \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\textwidth-#1\textwidth-.3\textwidth\relax}%%%
        #3%%%
    \end{minipage}%%%
}%%%

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}%%%
    \MYminipage{0.5}{\MYfigure{1}{imagename.jpg}{text}{text}}{\MYfigure{1}{imagename.jpg}{text}{text}}%%%
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

and it produces: [image]

but what i want to pruduce is:

[image]

Comment: Try `\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr#1\textwidth-.3\textwidth\relax}` respective `\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\textwidth-#1\textwidth-.3\textwidth\relax}`

Comment: Usage/syntax of `\dimexpr`, `\numexpr` etc is explained in the [e-TeX manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/systems/doc/etex/etex_man.pdf)

Comment: @Ulrich Diez thank you. But unfortunately it doesn't work like i meant. It put both images in first minipage (in the left column). I wanted them to be same width on the left side and the right side.

Comment: What columns?  With your example LaTeX enters horizontal mode for placing the minipages. This is the mode where LaTeX produces lines of text for a paragraph. Both minipages produced by \MYminipage will be of width 0.2\textwidth: (0.5-0.3)*\textwidth=0.2\textwith = (1-0.5-0.3)*\textwidth. They fit into the same line of text. The mentioned width will be considered the textwidth inside the minipages. As you don't use comment-chars for ending lines, the minipages will be separated from each other by a space.To see more clearly what happens, wrap the single minipages into `\fbox`-commands.

Comment: @UlrichDiez Thank you for your effort. i edited my question to make clear what exactly i intend to do.

Comment: You do not want a caption?

Comment: You have two images, each one with a caption. Width of images and caption below the image is to be .47\textwidth. Thus horizontal gap between images is to be .06\textwidth. So the horizontal placement is clear. But what about the vertical placement of pictures and captions in case you use two different images with different measurements and different captions? Shall the word "Figure" from both captions be aligned? Shall the top-margins of the images be aligned? Putting things in boxes for measuring and calculating vertical space to insert is easy.Just specify the needs for vert. placement. ;-)

Comment: Another question: What behavior regarding scaling and horizontal and vertical placement do you wish in case with (horizontal) width=.47\textwidth at least one image does vertically not fit on the page/frame? (with `\includegraphics` one can specify both hight and width and provide `keepaspectratio` to make sure the image is scaled either to height or to width so that in any case both given height and given width do not get exceeded.)

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\newcommand{\MYfigure}[4][]{%
  \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[#1]{images/#2}
        \ifx\relax#3\relax \else\caption[#4]{#3}\fi
  \end{figure}%
}

\begin{document}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\begin{frame}[plain]
\begin{minipage}{.47 \textwidth}
    \MYfigure[height=\textheight,width=\linewidth]{tiger}{}{}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}{.47 \textwidth}
    \MYfigure[height=\textheight,width=\linewidth]{tiger}{}{}
\end{minipage}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Maybe that you als need `keepaspectratio` as parameter for the image. It depends on the size of your image.

[image]